# Change config file by puppet - depend hostname

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I want to push some config file to my all servers by puppet. File is almost the same for all servers, but there is one change - hostname.

I've created module in puppet with manifest and temp-conf-file. I include to all node. All is fine.

My question is: how can i push that file to all server with change one/two lines in that file. But i don't want to set config file in modules for all. I want to use one file and during the push change in side two lines.

Thank you for help.

Best,

Rafal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a template.  Set your file resource to use content instead of source:

```
content => template("mymodule/temp-conf-file.erb"),
```

Then have the template substitute the hostname.  The template would be located in the templates subdirectory of your module:

```
# This file is managed by puppet
... random config stuff ...
hostname = <%= hostname %>
```

You can also use fqdn or something else.

Official documentation: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template.html

Comment: Thank you i will check it. But i need change two lines, one with hostname, one with ip address.

Comment: You want to look at facter's [ipaddress][http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/core_facts.html#ipaddress] fact. Facter returns a ton of facts about the environment. In your config file template, you can reference any facter fact freely, just like hostname above.